# Inserting 1 million+ rows/second into a database on Druid/Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, druid

We have a huge influx of data, around 8 million rows in 1 second. Each row has 12 numeric values(timestamp, integers and floats, but no text). I'm looking for Streaming inserts, but we can manage with Bulk inserts if it can achieve the speeds.

**Queries**: Our queries are basically aggregations.

I have looked at **Druid**, but it doesn't support nanosecond timestamps which is absolutely required for us. Has anyone successfully worked around this limitation?

Has anyone been successful in inserting 1 million+ rows/second in Cassandra? What kind of cluster does it require?

I can provide more specific information if necessary.

Comment: Voting to close, as asking for tool recommendations is considered "off topic."

Comment: Can I just edit it to ask questions about each of the DBMSs in the same post?

Comment: Edited now @Aaron.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look into kdb+ (from Kx Systems) for high-performance time-
series ingestion and CEP. Its timestamps have nanosecond granularity.

In a recent Industrial IoT application, with one modest server (2 cores), kdb+ maintained a sustained (7x24x365) ingestion rate of 4.5 million events per second with low CPU utilization. We used kdb+'s in-memory database, with frequent write-downs to its on-disk databases. No cluster was required.

[kdb+](/questions/tagged/kdb%2b)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the suggestion. I have looked at kdb. If I understand correctly, the whole DB is stored in-memory. What was your experience with kdb when querying on data that on-disk instead of in-memory? Also, if it is 4.5 million events per sec, won't your one node run out of disk space?

Comment: kdb+ has an in-memory and on-disk database, both can be queried together using the same q-sql srcipts. The on-disk database (often called a historical database - HDB) can store PBs of data, which given your volume of 8 million rows per second, sounds worthy of your investigation.

Comment: I was under the impression that kdb has really high query speed because it stores data in-memory. But, when the data is flushed to disk, and then you query on this historical data (stored in disk), then the query speed should be significantly slower. Did you experience this?

Comment: Note that kdb+ is a column-store database. Data on disk can be organized into partitions across directories as well as across different storage channels, providing parallelism during queries. Columns can be "indexed as well. Data on disk can be compressed as well and if it is sensor data (I am guessing yours is), there are many options to reduce storage. 



Although disk access is slower than memory, with the proper design,